# Php apply discount to multiple products evenly

Tags: php

Im trying to figure something out. I want to apply coupon/discount amount to multiple products evenly.

For example if I have an array with 3 items

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [price] => 10.00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [price] => 20.00
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [price] => 30.00
        )

)
```

my coupon vale is 10 $ off

and I have tried this:

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
   $data['price'] = ($row->price - 10 / 3) * 100
}
```

So basically I want to deduct from each item price proportionally total of 10 and end up with something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [price] => 7.50
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [price] => 17.50
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [price] => 25.00
        )

)
```

where total price sum is 50 instead original of 60

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: @u_mulder Problem is that it does not work.

Comment: It does not work __how__? Your pc explodes? You have white screen? You have incorrect results?

Comment: @u_mulder Dont have to be a smart a**, yes incorrect values, otherwize, I would not ask for help

Comment: What @u_mulder is trying to say is could you please show us the results of running that code ?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "applying evenly". In your result, you have subtracted $2.5 for the first item, also $2.5 from the second one and $5 from the last one. Don't you want to subtract `coupon_value / item_count` from each item? That would be evenly I would say.

Comment: Anyway, you should check Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: @Dawid Ferenczy yes I would like to distribute discount amount evenly among all items

Comment: Evenly means you divide 10 / 3 and substract $3.33 from each item, isn't it?

Comment: u_mulder , not really , for example if item price is 2.00, I cant subtract 3.33, it needs to be proportional based on item price

Comment: If you have 10$ discount, which is 1/6 of total price, then you need decrease every price to it's 1/6.

Comment: @u_mulder Ok, but I want to deduct more from items with higher price, so it needs to have some type of proportional subtraction.

Comment: "_Proportionally_" and "_evenly_" are two different things so you should decide what exactly you want first.

Comment: @Dawid Ferenczy Proportionally, is what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, from the comments under the question, you want to distribute the coupon value *proportionally* (not evenly) to prices of all items. That's pretty easy, it's more a mathematical problem than a programming one.

1. Calculate `x` as `coupon / sum(prices)`
2. Iterate through all items and subtract `x * item_price` from `item_price`
3. That's it.

For your example (`coupon = 10`, `prices = [10, 20, 30]`), the result is:

1. `x = 10 / 60 = 0.1666667`
2. Subtract `x * item_price` from each item's `item_price`:

   - `10 - 10 * 0.1666667 = 10 - 1.6666667 = 8.33333`
   - `20 - 20 * 0.1666667 = 20 - 3.3333333 = 16.6666`
   - `30 - 30 * 0.1666667 = 30 - 5 = 25`

To verify: `1.666667 + 3.3333333 + 5 = 10`

Comment: This is a great answer! Only thing is that what if your prices end in 0.99? Like $10.99, $12.99, etc. I've implemented this answer in my project, but it isn't very pretty as the discount per line ends up being 3 decimal places instead of 2.